# Exporting CPLEX TSP example solution to csv/excel

Tags: cplex, traveling-salesman

This might be a simple question but I have been struggling with this for a while.

I am using flow control to introduce lazy constraints when solving a problem that is very similar to a TSP. I found the CPLEX TSP example which I can follow well and use as a starting point to solve my problem.

Is there a way to export the solution of the CPLEX TSP example to a csv/excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

In [Excel, Rocket science and optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/) I shared an example

[image: Traveling salesman with Excel]

.mod

```
{int} solution=...;
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection s("travelingsalesman.xlsx");

solution to  SheetWrite(s,"output!B2:B1000");
```

[image: In the CPLEX IDE]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I have tried to follow this example but all I can seem to do is write the solution to the .dat file which then overwrites any of the code that was previously there. Is there something that I am missing here? Is there a way to maybe call another .dat file before the opl.end command that can handle writing to excel?

Comment: First you need to run the configuration TSP which builds tspresult.dat

Comment: This works now, thank you so much! I have one last question, is it possible to do the same for some other data type? So if for example I have an array which I write to tspresult.dat?

Comment: I have figured this out, and you can. You would just need to correctly define the data structure in the tspexport.mod. You really were very helpful, thansk Alex!